# $\int \limits_{X}cfd\mu=c\int \limits_{X}fd\mu$ if $c=\infty$ and $f\geqslant 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ - measure space and $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ and $f:X\to [0,\infty]$-measurable function and $c=\infty$. Prove that $$\int \limits_{X}cfd\mu=c\int \limits_{X}fd\mu \qquad (*)$$
**Proof:**

*Case 1.* Suppose that $\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=0$$\Rightarrow$ RHS of $(*)$ is equal $\infty \times 0=0$.

Also $f=0$ a.e. $\Rightarrow$ $A=\{x:f(x)=0\}$ and $B=\{x:f(x)>0\},$ where $\mu(B)=0$.
If $x\in A$ $\Rightarrow$ $cf(x)=0$. If $x\in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)>0 $ $\Rightarrow$ $cf(x)=\infty$. Hence: $$\int \limits_{X}cfd\mu=\int \limits_{A}cfd\mu+\int \limits_{B}cfd\mu=0+0=0.$$ So LHS of $(*)$ is also $0$.

*Case 2.*   Suppose that $\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=a>0$. Then $A=\{x: f(x)=0\}$ and $B=\{x:f(x)>0\}$, where $\mu(B)>0$, otherwise integral is zero.
If $x\in A$ $\Rightarrow$ $cf(x)=0$. If $x\in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)>0 $ $\Rightarrow$ $cf(x)=\infty.$ Hence: $$\int \limits_{X}cfd\mu=\int \limits_{A}cfd\mu+\int \limits_{B}cfd\mu=0+\infty=\infty.$$ So LHS of $(*)$ is also $\infty$.

*Case 3.*   Suppose that $\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=\infty$. Then $A=\{x: f(x)=0\}$ and $B=\{x:f(x)>0\}$, where $\mu(B)>0$, otherwise integral is zero.
If $x\in A$ $\Rightarrow$ $cf(x)=0$. If $x\in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)>0 $ $\Rightarrow$ $cf(x)=\infty.$ Hence: $$\int \limits_{X}cfd\mu=\int \limits_{A}cfd\mu+\int \limits_{B}cfd\mu=0+\infty=\infty.$$ So LHS of $(*)$ is also $\infty$.

What do you think about this proof? Would be very grateful for any suggestions and remarks.
Can anyone check my solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine Cases 2,3:

If $\int f  >0$ then 
for any natural $n$ we have $ nf \le c f$ and so 
$\int n f = n \int f \le \int cf$ and so
$\int cf = \infty$. It is immediate that $c \int f = \infty$.

Comment: Nice remark! Thanks